# Replace ansible line using lineinfile

Tags: regex, shell, ansible

Im working with ansible to change the line for https host

```
---
  - name: "change http to https"
    lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ install_dir }}/xx/abc-out.xml"
    state: present
    regexp: "<column name="PARAM_VALUE">http://host.com:42003</column>"
    line:  "<column name="PARAM_VALUE">https://host.com:42091</column>"

---
- name: Change line
  vars_files:
    - vars/conn.yml
  become_user: "{{ app_user }}"
  become: true
  roles:
      - { role: https-host }
```

It complain that the line is have a problem.
Can anyone help to point it out?

Comment: Is everyone supposed to guess what line it complains about?

Comment: Inside the string literal, there are unescaped `"`. Perhaps, you need to define the literal with single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes like this -

```
    regexp: '<column name="PARAM_VALUE">http://host.com:42003</column>'
    line:  '<column name="PARAM_VALUE">https://host.com:42091</column>'
```

Also, I see that the attributes `dest`, `state`, `regexp` and `line` are not indented correctly in the example you mentioned in your question. It should look like this -

```
---
- name: "change http to https"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ install_dir }}/xx/abc-out.xml"
    state: present
    regexp: '<column name="PARAM_VALUE">http://host.com:42003</column>'
    line:  '<column name="PARAM_VALUE">https://host.com:42091</column>'
```

Comment: Yeah, it can already. But I guess by using regexp the exact expression need to be exactly the same. I used as you mentioned.
regexp: '             <column name="PARAM_VALUE">http://host.com:42003</column>'

due to spacing infront. it works now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand the thing about spacing. Why do you need to give a space in front of the value? Doesn't it work without the extra space in front of the value?

Comment: Yep, the spacing need to be there, otherwise it will replace the space with the new line. This is due to the original file also have a spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp: '         <column name="PARAM_VALUE">https://host.com:12360</column>'
```

As I mentioned in the comment. The spacing and change to the single quote help.